# Redis StackExchange storing 500k classes

Tags: caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am attempting to put redis in place of an existing caching system which basically consists of `Dictionary<id, class>`. I have about 500k objects and am using the MsgPackObjectSerializer. I'm running into performance issues when attempting to retrieve the entire dataset.

Getting all the keys takes several seconds.

```
var keys = cacheClient.SearchKeys("ID:*").ToList();
```

and using the GetAll method in this fashion:

```
cacheClient.GetAll<class>(keys).Values;
```

results in a timeout even with a configuration of the following:

```
     var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
     configOptions.EndPoints.Add("localhost:6379");
     configOptions.ClientName = "RedisClient";
     configOptions.ConnectTimeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
     configOptions.SyncTimeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
     configOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
     configOptions.ResponseTimeout = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
```

The only way I've been able to get results back is in this manner:

```
var fromRedis = new ConcurrentDictionary<id, class>();
keys.AsParallel().ForAll(k =>
{
    var div = cacheClient.Get<class>(k);
    if (div != null)
    {
        fromRedis.TryAdd(k, div)
    }
});
```

Which doesn't seem right to me, and is very slow.

There must be a better way to do this that I am not seeing.

Update:
This is slightly faster than the keys.AsParallel call. Still takes 6 seconds...

```
     var insListScan = new List<Task<RedisValue[]>>();

     foreach (var batch in server.Keys(0, "InstrumentSK:*").Batch(1000))
     {
        var tran = cacheClient.Database.CreateTransaction();
        insListScan.Add(tran.StringGetAsync(batch.ToArray()));
        tran.Execute();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are looking for [SCAN](https://redis.io/commands/scan) command.

Because StackExchange.Redis aims to target scenarios such as cluster, it is important to know which commands target the database (the logical database that could be distributed over multiple nodes), and which commands target the server. The SCAN command target a single server.

[Here is](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan) you may find detailed explanation from StackExchange.Redis documentation and workaround for using SCAN.

Comment: Using a scan to get the keys made it faster, but I don't see anything about scanning except for hashes for actual object retrieval?

Comment: @Shawn it should be combined with get value for every key you got. To speed up this you should batch it by hand. Please write if you need example in answer.

Comment: I added an example of what I'm doing in the question.

Comment: @Shawn in example you are missing to use transactions (MULTY/EXEC) in loop. Right now you got batch of 1000 keys with your Keys/Batch statements and next iterate and execute each command in Redis ony by one. So you make  500k requests to server. You should make `batch.Select(k => k.ToString())).Values` with transaction. Please look here for example https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Transactions.md

Comment: Updated my example. It is slightly faster now. Are there any other improvements I can make?

Comment: @Shawn. yes, you should try to move SCAN+GET logic to LUA script inside Redis server.